# Pillow can not find image compiled by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I hope you are doing good.
Long story short I tried to do troll program for my friend but it lead into small problem.
When I tried to compile it from .py to .exe nothing seemed to work. It seems like it PIL library
does not see my BSOD.png Image ,but I imported it when i was compiling my project.
Here is the error it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "PIL\Image.py", line 3247, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\Murad\\PycharmProjects\\Sia'sTroll\\dist\\BSOD.png"
```

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import datetime
import win32api
import random
import mouse
import os

TimeList = ["1300", "1210", "1125", "1040", "0945"]
ChosenTime = TimeList[random.randint(0, 4)]

User = os.getlogin()

ScreenWidth = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
ScreenHeight = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)

BSOD = PILImage.open("BSOD.png")
BSOD.thumbnail((ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))
BSOD.save(fr"C:\Users\{User}\Documents\BSODTrueSize.png")

def CallBSOD():
    Root = Tk()
    Root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    Root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    BSODPhotoImage = PhotoImage(file=fr"C:\Users\{User}\Documents\BSODTrueSize.png")
    BSODLabeledImage = Label(image=BSODPhotoImage)
    BSODLabeledImage.pack()

    Root.after(random.randint(15, 60) * 1000, lambda: Root.destroy())
    Root.mainloop()

CallBSOD()

# while True:
#     CurrentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M"))
#     if CurrentTime == ChosenTime:
#         CallBSOD()
#         break
```

I use pyinstaller to compile so here is what i write in terminal when i want to compile my program: `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "C:/Users/Murad/PycharmProjects/Sia'sTroll/BSOD.png;." main.py`

I already tried using absolute path but nothing worked I also used auto py to exe several times but nothing changed since then

Comment: `Sia'sTroll` in the path may be the problem.

Comment: Typo error `PhotoImage(file=fr"C:\...` should be `PhotoImage(file=r"C:\...` drop lower character 'f'

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.

Comment: Toyota supra thx for commenting but by deleting 'f' before string it will think that User is part of the string not valuable